# C++ Function to Parse a String into Tokens

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing, pointers

I'm trying to build a function that takes in a c-string and a pointer to an array of character pointers and should return the number of tokens found while putting each token into an array of pointers to character pointers. For example if I pass in the string `ls -l file`, it should put into a an array of c-strings that has each word in a line (`args[1] = "I\0", args[2] = "am\0", args[3] = "the\0", args[4] = "test\0", args[5] = "string\0"`). Thanks for any help!

Here's what I have so far, but I am getting memory access violations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int MakeArg(char [], char** []);

int main()
{
    char str[] = "I am the test string";
    char** argv;
    int argc;

    argc = MakeArg(str, &argv);

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\nPress enter to quit.";
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}

int MakeArg(char s[], char** args[])
{
    int word = 1;   

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) //iterates through every character in s
    {
        *args[word][i] = s[i]; //adds each character to word
        if (s[i] == ' ') //when a space is found
        {
            *args[word][i] = '\0'; //it replaces it with a nullbyte in args
            word++; //and moves on to the next word
        }
    }

    return word; //returns number of words
}
```

Comment: `argv` is uninitialized.

Comment: Aside from that problem, consider using `std::vector` and `<algorithm>`.

Comment: ... and more than anything, `std::string`

Comment: Check this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/95976